# PHP - include file with POST data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, include

I have a PHP file which takes POST data. I run this file currently through AJAX in jQuery:

```
$.post("myfile.php", { key: value });
```

I want to run this same file but within another PHP script. This is what I want to achieve:

```
<?php

include("myfile.php", array("key" => "value") );

?>
```

I know that the `include` function doesn't take other parameters, so is there a way to include another PHP file with POST variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$_POST` superglobal array is writeable in a PHP script, so:

```
<?php

$_POST["key"] = "value";
include("myfile.php");

?>
```

Comment: I think this does not answer the OP question. Maybe he already knew that the $_POST could be modified but didn't know whether when including files the $_POST variable was kept.

Comment: In fact, @burzum's answer does much better.

Comment: The answer was accepted by the OP a year ago, therefore it must have answered his/her question. I do not know why you made your comment and downvote after a year, it makes no sense. Please use your free time to produce original answers to actual questions instead.

Comment: all right. I'd take the downvote out if I could, I can't btw.

Answer (score 5):

Any post data should be accessible everywhere in your scripts using $_POST.

So just use the post data in your myfile.php by accessing it through $_POST['key'] to get your value.

Comment: In fact any variable defined outside the include function should be accessible by the included script if placed after the variable definition.